# What is that cursor-like thing at the top of a Qt MainWindow?

Tags: qt, window

What is the circled part of the application called? [image: screenshot]

How can I get rid of it?

Comment: That looks like a toolbar, though it wouldn't be there unless you had added it yourself.

Comment: When I drag it, it scrolls around the window, like a scrollbar, but I did not add it and it seems to be default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is default toolbar (It is created automatically if your mainwidget is QMainWindow and you have ui form with it). To get rid of it, do something like this:

look at class diagram, when editing your *.ui file and remove `QToolBar`, named `mainToolBar` by default, like here -[image].

or you can use `void QMainWindow::removeToolBar ( QToolBar * toolbar )` - [docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmainwindow.html#removeToolBar)

or you can just hide through css or any means possible ( mainToolBar->hide() )

```
mainWindow->setStyleSheet( "QMenuBar { border: none } QToolBar { border: none }" );
// or
toolBar->setStyleSheet( "border: none" );
menubar->setStyleSheet( "border: none" );
```

Comment: I don't get any toolbars by default in designer when creating a QMainWindow, and if one has one in the .ui, it should be possible to remove it also via the designer UI again.

Comment: -1 for providing ugly way to hide toolbar through CSS. And this is a toolbar, not a toolbar break. Toolbar break is a vertical line between toolbar items. @Frank Osterfeld, it can be removed by invoking its context menu in Designer and choosing remove.

Comment: Well, I found out that I was wrong about toolbar break. It's similar to line break, it allows to display toolbars on multiple rows in one toolbar area. But it still isn't the thing OP was asking about, and `removeToolBarBreak` certainly isn't helpful here.

Comment: @Riateche if you didn't noticed, in my solution, setstylesheet is not the only way, just one of possible ways. Including suggestion to remove  toolbar manually from designer. That you took, rewrited and posted as your answer and minused out mine. Way to go.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld tried uot myself, it is included by default, if you create qmainwindow as main widget with ui forms. And yes, i indeed included that option in my answer

Comment: Altering CSS is a wrong solution. Obviously OP wants to remove the toolbar, not to hide it with this hacks. If you apply your CSS, toolbar will still exist, take space in layout, respond to mouse events, etc. Also it can cause troubles in the future if OP will want to add an useful toolbar. Of course it's not bad to provide ALL possible ways in your answer. But if you want to describe such an awful solution, you should add a warning about it.

Comment: @Riateche shylesheets was never the main solution (it was 3 a.m, so i delayed fancy formating for later), just one possibly way, if op wants to hide it. I provided removetoolbar method and suggested removing manually via creator. And you still didn't explained, why you took part of my answer, rewrited it, posted as your own instead of comment or suggest edit?

Comment: I didn't rewrited your answer. I've posted my own answer which I wrote in the way this question should be answered in my opinion. I disagree with your answer but I can't fix it myself. The best I can do is to add a comment, downvote and write better answer. If I'm wrong, votes will tell us that.

Comment: @Riateche no, your whole answer was included in mine as just one of solution, you just took it, rewrited and downvoted mine. i DID suggest to remove it toolbar manually as suggest the bunch of other solutions, and you after 6 hours come in, downvoting this answer, take one of solutions and post it is your own. I strongly diagree with this. I would understand doing this, if i was not reacting to comments, and didn't make any adjustment, but it is clearly not the case.

Comment: Well, now your question gets better, I'll cancel my downvote. However I don't understand why do you call it 'rewrite'. We don't make up solutions, it's not a piece of art. One of your solutions is the same as mine. It's not surprising because there are quite few solutions. If there were no your answer, my answer still would be the same as it is now. And if I argeed with your answer, I would not post my own. I think we should finish this pointless discussion.

Comment: There is one more disturbing thing to me. I also was sure that one toolbar is added to main window by default in Qt Designer. I'm sure I've experienced this several times, but now I have checked it by creating new form class or new project in Qt Creator, and there is no toolbar by default! I'm confused.

Comment: @Riateche yeah, i guess, i carried away a lot. This morning tested a few combinations - QMainWindow as main window without Ui form has no toolbar, WITH form - it has toolbar. QWidget as mainwidget has no toolbar with or without form